# $\mathbb{Z}\setminus U$ is open, where U is a basic open set of $\mathcal{B}$, the set of all arithmetic progressions

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $m, b \in \mathbb Z$ with $m \neq 0$, and $U$ is of the form $Z(m, b) = \{ mx + b \mid x \in \mathbb Z \}$

I'm not sure how to show $\mathbb{Z}\setminus U$  is open, I was thinking to expressing $\mathbb{Z}\setminus U$ as a union of arithmetic progressions, since $\mathbb{Z} = Z(1,0)$ and $Z(1,0) - Z(m,b) = Z(x,0)$ for $x \notin  Z(m,b)$. 
I was wondering if if this makes sense and if there is a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\Bbb Z\setminus Z(m,b)$ is a union of arithmetic progressions. HINT:

$$\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{r=0}^{|m|-1}Z(m,r)\;,$$

and the $|m|$ sets in that union are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: would it just be $\bigcup_{r=1}^{|m|-1}Z(m,r)$ since we are taking out one set ?

Comment: @jia: Not quite, because $Z(m,0)$ may not be the right set to remove. You have to remove the set $Z(m,r)$ that is equal to $Z(m,b)$. How can you calculate the right $r$ from $m$ and $b$?

Comment: $\bigcup_{r=1}^{|m|-1}Z(m,r + b)$ This will ensure b is not in the set. Is this correct ?

Comment: @jia: Yes, that will work. In case you’re interested, I had a slightly different approach in mind: $Z(m,b)=Z(m,b\bmod m)$, and $0\le b\bmod m<m$, so we can also write it as $$\bigcup\left\{Z(m,r):0\le r<|m|\text{ and }r\not\equiv b\pmod{m}\right\}\;.$$ Yours is easier to write down.